# Problems with Firestore while sreating Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to create a firestore database but there is no option[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pD8B.png)

I'm having some issues with Cloud Firestore. For the first time it worked but after refreshing its showing "This project is set up to use Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. This mode can only be accessed from the Google Cloud Console"